# Bash is interpreting my JSON CLI argument differently than local, and ignores all keys but one

Tags: bash, aws-lambda, aws-cli

I am using the AWS CLI on a Jenkins server, and one of the argument flags requires a JSON body.

I've tried escaping double quotes and etc., but nothing seems to work on Jenkins. Locally, however, everything works fine. This is my command:

```
aws lambda update-function-configuration \
--region us-east-1 \
--function-name traxcess-web \
--environment '{"Variables":{"DEVEX_CLIENT_ID":"****", "DEVEX_CLIENT_SECRET":"****", "STATIC_DIR":"lib/build"}}'
```

The error is saying that I'm using "Unknown Options": `Unknown options: STATIC_DIR:lib/build}}, DEVEX_CLIENT_SECRET:****,`

The other interesting caveat here is that if I only upload one argument, everything functions correctly.

Am I providing my JSON incorrectly?

Edit:

```
/opt/runtime/ruby-2.2.6/bin/awssume aws lambda update-function-configuration --region us-east-1 --function-name traxcess-web --environment '{"Variables":{"VAR":"hi", "VAR2":"hi2", "STATIC_DIR":"lib/build"}}'
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help

Unknown options: STATIC_DIR:lib/build}}, VAR2:hi2,
```

Comment: You don't need to escape double quotes inside single quotes. The command looks fine to me. Are you trying to send this command using `ssh` ?

Comment: Take a look at the shorthand syntax in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/update-function-configuration.html, maybe that will work better.

Comment: Shorthand doesn't work either, same problem. It will only read one argument. We're also not doing SSH, it runs as part of a deployment script on Jenkins.

Comment: Maybe the problem is with embedding this into Jenkins.

Comment: I have a feeling this is a quoting problem. It looks like the single quoted string ends too early; is this all in a single quoted string in Jenkins? Can you show the Jenkins snippet that calls this?

Comment: I think you might have a single quote in one of your redacted secrets. Could you confirm this isn't the case?

Comment: I'm now using hardcoded secrets and it's giving a similar error. It's still splitting in a strange way.